GestureDetector not working within a SizedBox
I have the below widget that creates a CircularIconButton. I want to have a GestureDetector such that the whole space that this widget takes can be tapped and some action done. Here's an image of what it looks like below:

But no matter what I do, it doesn't seem to want to work and and I don't even see the GestureDetector being shown in the widget tree.

Here's the code that I have:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fti_team_member_app_v3/features/theme/theme_constants.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

/// Creates a circular icon button with a text footer that links to a url.
class CircularIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The button title.
  final String title;

  /// The button icon.
  final IconData icon;

  /// The url to link to.
  final String url;

  /// The width of the button container.
  final double containerWidth;

  /// The height of the button container.
  static const double containerHeight = 160;

  /// The height of the button.
  static const double buttonHeight = 100;

  const CircularIconButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.title,
      required this.icon,
      required this.url,
      this.containerWidth = 125});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: containerWidth,
      height: containerHeight,
      child: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
        onTap: () async {
          if (!await launchUrl(Uri.parse(url))) {
            throw Exception('Could not launch ${Uri.parse(url)}');
          }
        },
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: buttonHeight,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: null,
                style: primaryButtonStyle.copyWith(
                  shape: WidgetStateProperty.all<CircleBorder>(
                      const CircleBorder()),
                ),
                child: Icon(icon),
              ),
            ),
            // The title of the button.
            Align(
              child: Text(
                title,
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                maxLines: 3,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: meta.copyWith(color: ftiDarkGray),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I've tried moving around where the GestureDetector is placed in hopes that it would fix it but nothing has worked thus far.

I have tried your code and it's working fine. GestureDetector is working and also I have tried wrapping it in InkWell. Try flutter clean or Remove Invalidate Caches from your project.

Some times GestureDetector is not working on SizedBox ,Container, or other Widgets use Inkwell instead of this.
